# Unix shell directory history

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line-interface, history

The history feature is great for remembering commands. Is there a feature that remembers recent directories?

I'd like to be able to search through a history of directories - it'd be even better if it was possible to bookmark and name them, as you can do in a browser.

Comment: you can create link to our favorite dir a with `ln -s`

Answer (score 2):

You can do `cd -1` to get back to the previous directory, `cd -2` to get to the former etc.. You can also refer to them using `~1`, like `cp ~1/README.md ~2/`

For a more advanced use, you can use the `dirs` builtin. You can also use `pushd` and `popd` to stack up directories and get back to them later on, pretty useful in scripts.

cf the [directory stack](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Directory-Stack.html#The-Directory-Stack)

Zsh has the same facility, the [dirstack](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/workshops/zsh/dir_stack.html). And with zsh, you can have more fun with [directory bookmarks](http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2015-zsh-directory-bookmarks.html),

Finally, there's even a crazy guy who implemented [a GUI for listing the dirstack](http://scottlab.ucsc.edu/mystuff/gdirs.html). Not sure how useful that can be, but it's definitely crazy enough to be referred :-)

HTH

Comment: Thank you, those are good points. I'm familiar with the pushd and popd commands. I'm looking for something that does this automatically, so, if I come back, after a few days away from something, and don't remember where it was, I can just look at my directory stack and see where I've been.

Comment: well, that's the whole point of the dirstack's `dirs` command then

Answer (score 1):

To save directories and keep a historial, you can try `pushd` and `popd` from bash

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I provide an answer, but ok, critique was not necessary... i delete it